# Como trocar/permutar o valor de duas variáveis

Tags: java

Estou com dificuldades para escreve esse exercício na Linguagem Java, usando a IDE Eclipse:

> Ler dois valores para as variáveis A e B, efetuar a troca dos valores de forma que a variável A passe a possuir o valor da variável B e que a variável B passe a possuir o valor da variável A. Apresentar os valores trocados.

Eu sei que preciso declarar a Variável A, a Variável B e Uma Variável Auxiliar!

No caso eu consigo apenas fazer com que A Variável A fique com o valor da Variável B! Porem a Variável B apresenta o próprio valor e não apresenta o Valor de A que é o que Preciso!

MEU CÒDIGO:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Variavel {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

     int VarA;
     int VarB;
     int Aux;

     System.out.println("Digite a Primeira Variavel");

     Scanner Lera = new Scanner(System.in);
     VarA= Lera.nextInt();

     System.out.println("Digite a Primeira Variavel");
     VarB= Lera.nextInt();



     VarA=VarB;

     Aux=VarA;

     VarB=Aux;

     System.out.println("O valor de A é: " +VarB);
     System.out.println("O valor de B é: " +Aux);
     Lera.close();



    }

}
```

> OBS: Estou no incio das Aulas de JAVA,portanto por enquanto so uso os comando basicos como INT,Scanner,Read? Ainda não aprendi FOR,WHILE,IF,ELSE

IMAGEM DO RESULTADO

[image: Tela Com O Resultado Usando Eclipse]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem dois problemas.

A forma de trocar está errada assim como a forma como usa a variáveis no `println`também.

Altere para:

```
//Guarada o valor de A
Aux=VarA;
//A variável VarA, como já foi guardado o valor de A, pode agora receber o valor de B
VarA=VarB;
//O valor de A, anteriormente guardado na variável Aux, é atribuído à variável VarB
VarB=Aux;

//Como as variáveis têm agora os valores trocados deve usá-las no println na sequência correcta
System.out.println("O valor de A é: " +VarA);
System.out.println("O valor de B é: " +VarB);
```

Answer (score 5):

Seu erro foi alterar o valor da variavel `VarA` antes de armazenar o valor dela na variavel `Aux`:

```
 Aux=VarA;
 VarA=VarB;
 VarB=Aux;
```

Dessa forma, irá funcionar corretamente. Altere também a exibição:

```
 System.out.println("O valor de A é: " +VarA);
 System.out.println("O valor de B é: " +VarB);
```

Dessa forma exibirá as variáveis já com os valores trocados, como pode ser visto no ideone: https://ideone.com/Ur4ImH

Vale ressaltar que, em java, nomes de variáveis devem iniciar com letra minúscula, seguindo o padrão [Camel Case](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) para nomes compostos.

Comment: Ele apresenta os valores diferentes,porém nao os altera!            
                                                                                                      
 Digite a Primeira Variavel
2
Digite a Primeira Variavel
6
O valor de A é: 2
O valor de B é: 6

Comment: @CarolM você quer exibir os valores trocados das variáveis?

Comment: Articuno - Sim,é exatamente isso! A tem que apresentar o valor de B e B tem que apresentar o Valor de A!

Comment: @CarolM corrigido.

Comment: Articuno ,duas perguntas fora do contexto : Tenho como escolher mais de uma resposta como a melhor delas?     E como posso falar com quem me respondeu (igual um chat)?

Comment: @CarolM só pode aceitar uma, mas você pode votar nas duas, fica a seu criterio escolher :)